# Creating a database and connection with client for PostgreSQL on OSX

Tags: postgresql, osx-mavericks

How can I start a PostgreSQL database and connect with a client in terminal?

I've tried this after installing postgreSQL with brew.

```
which psql
```

Results in this:

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

Then I try to start database with:

```
pg_ctl init -D /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Which gives:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "matt".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_AU.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: could not access directory "/usr/local/bin/psql": Not a directory
pg_ctl: database system initialization failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a data directory first and input its name after -D. Say if the data directory you created is /usr/local/bin/psql, then your init command will be

```
pg_ctl init -D /usr/local/bin/psql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PostgreSQL [pg_ctl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html) documentation:

> -D datadir
>
> --pgdata datadir
>
> Specifies the file system location of the database configuration files. If this is omitted, the environment variable PGDATA is used.

You are specifying your `pgsql` executable as your data directory.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm looking for the complete set of steps needed to start and use a database through the client ie how to find the directories and which commands